ssues Installing Cisco Packet Tracer on Ubuntu Due to Unmet Dependencies
I'm having trouble installing Cisco Packet Tracer on my Ubuntu system due to unmet dependencies. Here’s a detailed description of the issue and the steps I have taken so far:
System Details:
OS: Ubuntu noble
Packet Tracer Version: 8.2.2
Installer File: Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb
Issue:
When I attempt to install Packet Tracer using the dpkg command, I encounter the following errors:
$ sudo dpkg -i Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb
Selecting previously unselected package packettracer.
(Reading database ... 429297 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb ...
Unpacking packettracer (8.2.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on libgl1-mesa-glx; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.
 packettracer depends on libxcb-xinerama0-dev; however:
  Package libxcb-xinerama0-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.4-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packettracer

Steps Taken:
sudo apt update

sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx libxcb-xinerama0

Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.

However, this returns:
Request:
Could anyone provide guidance on how to successfully install Packet Tracer on my Ubuntu system? Specifically, how can I resolve the unmet dependencies for libgl1-mesa-glx and libxcb-xinerama0-dev?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Does this answer your question? How to download a software package with all dependencies and sub-dependencies?

click here for download dependecies
  sudo apt install gdebi

  sudo gdebi ./libgl1-mesa-glx_20.3.5-1_amd64.deb

  sudo gdebi ./YOURPACKETTRACKERARCHIVE.deb 


Seems like a good part answer but where are the steps to install this stuff?
